# Different result when running lm() inside function or outside of it

Tags: r

The function:

```
linear_regression <- function(dataframe, target) {

  model = lm(target ~ .,data = dataframe)

  return(model)

}
```

I am using dataframe called test2, target column is called `DP_POWER- DP_POWER`

Running this outside:

```
lm(test2$`DP_POWER- DP_POWER` ~ .,data = test2)
```

results in

```
Call:
lm(formula = test2$`DP_POWER- DP_POWER` ~ ., data = test2)

Coefficients:
                                  (Intercept)  `OTHER VARIABLE`  
                                     1154.789                                          1.134
```

Running this inside the function by calling:

```
linear_regression(dataframe = test2, target = test2$`DP_POWER- DP_POWER`)
```

returns

```
Call:
lm(formula = target ~ ., data = dataframe)

Coefficients:
                                  (Intercept)                           `DP_POWER- DP_POWER`  
                                   -1.807e-10                                      1.000e+00  
`OTHER VARIABLE`  
                                   -1.552e-15
```

as you can clearly see, running my user made function for some reason computes the DP_POWER- DP_POWER, whereas running it in console does not.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: I know I agree, but I cannot figure out how to pass it as an argument without it being an object that already exists.

Comment: by that I mean if I try to do `linear_regression(dataframe = test2, target = DP_POWER- DP_POWER)` I get object does not exist.

Comment: thank you I will read up on this, I tried using character to string but it gave me same issue. `eval(parse(text = target))` also gave me same issue. I will try look up `reformulate`

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with the help of 李哲源 when he recommended using as.formula(paste())

```
linear_regression <- function(dataframe, target) {

  model = lm(as.formula(paste(target, '~ .')),data = dataframe)

  return(model)

}
```